# How to enable the equations, figures and tables references from latex to odt/docx using pandoc?

Tags: cross-referencing, pandoc, msword, export, open-office

Due requeriments of the work, I must send reports in docx format. This part is done without problem, but in the resulting document there is no reference to the equations and figures (i.e.: the numbered equations and the Fig. xx captions). Besides that, the reference appears as

```
verify the equation[eq:22]
```

instead of

```
verify the equation 22
```

and in the figures appears as

```
Equivalent circuit in small signal 
[f8]
```

instead of

```
Figure 8: Equivalent circuit in small signal
```

I have used `pandoc`, `latex2rtf`, `make4ht`

An extract of the file as MWE

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2,
 breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\let\myTOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{}
  \myTOC
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagenumbering{arabic} }

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\noindent \listoffigures

\title{\noindent {\large{}Title}}

\maketitle
\noindent {\large{}\tableofcontents{}}{\large}

\section{{\large{}Text}}

\noindent TextText and more Text

\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\pagebreak{}
\end{itemize}
\noindent 

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\noindent Text to make reference to \ref{f1}
\noindent 
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{pasted1}
\caption{Caption}
\label{f1}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
a_{1}=-g_{m1}(r_{o2}\sslash r_{o4})\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}


\noindent adjusting the  \ref{eq:1}  
\noindent \medskip{}

\end{document}
```

And the methods used

1. **Pandoc**

   pandoc  -s -f latex  --toc --number-sections  --toc-depth=2 --filter pandoc-crossref -M autoEqnLabels -M tableEqns -M autoSectionLabels -M chapters   -M codeBlockCaptions -M cref -M numberSections -M figLabels  -o output.docx -t docx input.tex
2. **latex2rtf**

latex2rtf output.rtf input.tex

- **latexmk** -pdf input.tex

  latexmk -pdf input.tex
  make4ht -f odt input.pdf

Albeit the math is correctly translated and rendered, and the overall quality of the process is very good, the references are wrong, sometimes even when the reference to the figure appears ok, the number is incorrect (in the next image says figure 9, but it should be 8).
There are lots of references so editing manually its a no go. And almost I forgot, these document is supposed to be the chapter 2, and in the conversion the numbering isnt conserved, even when its adjusted via the
`\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` (for the toc)
and

```
  \setcounter{section}{1}
```

for the rest of the document.

The output look like this
[image]

So, is there a way to adjust the references? (be to docx or odt).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked that  "verify the equation[eq:22]"  is not just "verify the equation 22"  when printed or exported to PDF?

Comment: yes, but it seems that pandoc does not support equation and figures numbering when a docx is generated, so it has to be done manually.

Comment: And in the pdf is done correctly, the issue is when the output fornat is docx (and odt too).